# remainder application in ruby

Tags: ruby

i want to send develop a web app in ruby on rails . which wil send the remainder to the mail and mobile tooo . can some body help me out

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The easy way I would do it is have a scheduler that would sent reminders.

There's several schedulers available. Here's one: http://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler

For the mailer, you can use the provided mailer in Rails; ActionMailer::Base (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html)